# Go to next record from Asp.Net MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

I've started working in asp.net MVC a few months ago. I'm using MVC4 with EF5.0 in C# at the moment.

-I haven't found a straight answer and working solution for this apparently simple situation...

**Question**: In controller action I want to be able to move to the next record based on the actual ID I'm seeing in the view. I'm trying to have a link or button in the view, to navigate to the next record. Please be aware it's not the next sequence number (as the ID you're seeing is 245 and the next record could have the ID 296).

I've tried this approach (similar from another post):

**In Controller** (*Edit Method*):

```
        `// Pk is the id that is passed into the Edit method
        var nextID = db.Customers.OrderBy(i => i.Pk)
                                 .SkipWhile(i => i.Pk != customer.Pk)
                                 .Skip(1)
                                 .Select(i => i.Pk);

        ViewBag.NextID = nextID;
        ...
        ...some other not relevant code...
        ...            
        return View(customer);`
```

But then, 
**In View** the ViewBag.NextID is receiving:  System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1  (instead of the next id 296).

Any help, suggestions, tips are welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your LINQ query returns an `IQuerable<Customer>`. If you want to return a single Customer, you'll have to use either `.First()` or `.Single()` at the end of the query. But, you can also make your query simpler, like this:

```
var nextID = db.Customers.OrderBy(i => i.Pk).First(i => i.Pk > customer.Pk).Pk;
```

This will return the first Customer ID (Pk) greater than the given one.

Comment: Thanks ataravati.. I could have done something wrong, although I'm receiving an error: Error 1 'Catalog.Models.Customer' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Catalog.Models.Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Before I have...

`Customer customer = db.Customers.Single(c => c.Pk == id);`

Anyway I've used a little different approach and I think it's working...will update my question.

Thank you again so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told it to return a single item. If you add something like `.First()` to the end of your LINQ query, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks Chris and weldsonandrade.. It doesn't work in my case, I could have done something wrong, although I think it could be caused by the skipwhile.
Anyway I've used a little different approach and I think it's working...will update my question.

Thank you again so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that in an environment where the result might not return anything, it is often said that you should use FirstOrDefault as that will not bomb if no results exist and will return the default value for that type. First() on the other hand will throw an exception if no records are found.